# "Converted PDF file" - what does it really mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expression-choice, technical

I can press Ctrl+P on my keyboard and save this HTML page as PDF. Would it be correct to call such a file a *converted PDF file*? Or does the word *converted* mean that the file was converted *from* PDF to something different?

In other words,

1. converted PDF file = HTML file saved as PDF (or Markdown file converted to PDF using Pandoc)
2. converted PDF file = PDF file converted to e.g. DOC

Which version is correct, 1 or 2?

Comment: I researched the first page of Google results: "converted PDF file" means "some other format converted into PDF" in 7/10 whereas it means "PDF converted into some other format" in 3/10 results.

Comment: I would call it a "PDF file".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can press Ctrl+P on my keyboard and save this HTML page as PDF. Would it be correct to call such a file a converted PDF file?

No. You should not do this because of possible ambiguity. Because of [the frequency of "convert [something] [in]to X" as opposed to relative rarity of "convert [something] from X"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=converted%20from%2Cconverted%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconverted%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconverted%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconverted%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconverted%20to%3B%2Cc0), the listener will assume the "into" version, and this is not what you want.

You will have to say "the new PDF file."

**Long answer:**

Past participles as adjectives generally take on a passive function:

The **washed** car = The car that has been washed. = The indicated/specific car that has undergone the action of washing *and must now already be in its new state.*

The **fed** dog = the dog that has been fed. = The indicated/specific dog that has undergone the action of washing *and must now already be in its new state.*

The **converted** document = The indicated/specific document that has been converted.  The indicated/specific document that has undergone the action of conversion *and must now  already be in its new state.*

Note the past tense of the participle: the action has taken place in the past, thus the indicated noun is currently in the new state.

**To convert** is ambitransitive but carries with it a mandatory adverbial complement (**[in]to** X, or **from** X) that can be explicit or implicit.

A: Where is he living?
B: In the house.
A: There is no house on his land - there is only a shed.
B: He converted the shed. = He converted the shed *into a house*.

"He converted the house from the shed" is not particularly idiomatic - it sounds awkward - we would say "He made the house from the shed."

To convert **[in]to** and to convert **from** are not phrasal verbs because **[in]to** and **from** are true prepositions. As such, the preposition cannot be expressed in the passive.

*this is a converted **[in]to** PDF file./ *this is a converted **from** PDF file.

Thus a converted PDF file = a PDF file that has been converted **[in]to** another format - Thus a converted PDF document would have originally been a PDF file that is now in another format, e.g. a .docx format.

We can see this in

"By flattening the head of a large nail, he converted that nail into a screwdriver. He then used **the converted nail** to unscrew the box."

The alternative could *grammatically* be a PDF file that has been converted, **from** another format, but this is redundant in your context, as it is obvious that the file is in the PDF format and does not require a description - it speaks for itself.

*"By flattening the head of a large nail, he converted that nail into a screwdriver. He then used **the converted screwdriver** to unscrew the box."

and

A: "How did you open the box?"
B: *"By converting a screwdriver from a nail".

Comment: Thanks a lot, Greybeard. There are 4 mysterious asterisks in your answer - I suppose they are by intent, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @jsv the askerisk indicates that an example is wrong: *"He said he **do** like it":  of course, correctly, it should be "He said he **does** like it."