# Word to describe a PDF file produced by converting from another format (for example, from HTML)

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, paired-word-requests

A month ago, I asked whether it would be correct to call an HTML page saved as PDF file a *converted PDF file*.

> ["Converted PDF file" - what does it really mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/555779)

According to Greybeard, the answer is "no"; a *converted PDF file* is the PDF file that is converted **to** something different, for example, to PNG.

Is there a word, probably a neologism, or maybe a phrase rather than a word, to refer to such files, and which will point to their converted-from nature?

```
Some table.

ID    Article    Format and source of original file    Converted PDF (we need another word!)
--    -------    ----------------------------------    -------------------------------------
01    Abc xyz    HTML, https://...                     abc_xyz.pdf
02    Xyz abc    PDF, https://...                      n/a
03    Aaa        HTML, https://...                     aaa.pdf
04    Bbb        HTML, https://...                     abb.pdf
```

I can cheat and call the files in the 4th column "converted HTMLs", but there are some drawbacks. For example, the original file may be in EPUB rather than HTML format.

Comment: Did you consider "Resultant PDF"?

Comment: @KillingTime This is very interesting idea, thanks. (And I think it could be an answer.)

Comment: You're fighting the tide on this one, because almost every PDF created is created from something else.

Comment: English is potentially ambiguous in this respect. If I say *My essay was copied*, that could either mean that ***I** plagiarised it [from some other source]* OR that ***other people** plagiarised the essay that I wrote*. I think there's a literary (and/or *linguistic*) term for this kind of "agent / patient ambiguity", but I don't recall it.

Comment: It’s just the PDF version of the file